# Как создать параметры для текста в JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, javascript-faq

В первом input user пишет что то и при нажатии на publish отображается результат в h1
во втором input пишется размер текста например 15px
в третьем - font-family
в четвертом - цвет текста
в пятом - background-color
нужно чтобы при клике set styles эти параметры применились к h1[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вы хотите получить ответ, не поленитесь пожалуйста, добавьте код в сниппет.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```js
let h = document.getElementById('h');
let fs = document.getElementById('font-size');
let fc = document.getElementById('font-color');
let btn = document.getElementById('apply');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  h.style.fontSize = `${fs.value}px`;
  h.style.color = fc.value;
});
```

```html
<h1 id="h">Text</h1>
<input id="font-size" placeholder="size"/>
<input id="font-color" placeholder="color"/>
<button id="apply">Apply</button>
```

Такая примерно логика.

Comment: Спасибо очень помогли